# CPU bounded I/O performance issue with NVMe drive on Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, performance, io, nvme

I have an NVIDIA Jetson TX2 system with an NVMe drive with pcie gen2 x4 speed. The system is running a Linux 4.9 kernel, and I am experiencing issues with write performance. My aim is to write sequential data to the disk at around 260 MB/s. I believe the hardware should be supporting this. Using `fio` for benchmarking

```
fio --name=seq_write --filename=testfile --size=10G --bs=2m --rw=write --time_based --runtime=20 --direct=1 --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=1 --output=seq-write-direct.out
```

I can see that when buffers are bypassed I get a write speed of around 870 MB/s.

```
seq_write: (g=0): rw=write, bs=(R) 2048KiB-2048KiB, (W) 2048KiB-2048KiB, (T) 2048KiB-2048KiB, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=1
fio-3.1
Starting 1 process

seq_write: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=3639: Tue Mar  9 17:28:02 2021
  write: IOPS=414, BW=829MiB/s (870MB/s)(16.2GiB/20001msec)
    slat (usec): min=319, max=3021, avg=1187.86, stdev=754.71
    clat (usec): min=570, max=3826, avg=1077.90, stdev=139.89
     lat (usec): min=1624, max=4674, avg=2266.94, stdev=645.00
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[  709],  5.00th=[  799], 10.00th=[  807], 20.00th=[ 1012],
     | 30.00th=[ 1074], 40.00th=[ 1106], 50.00th=[ 1123], 60.00th=[ 1123],
     | 70.00th=[ 1123], 80.00th=[ 1156], 90.00th=[ 1172], 95.00th=[ 1287],
     | 99.00th=[ 1303], 99.50th=[ 1303], 99.90th=[ 1352], 99.95th=[ 1434],
     | 99.99th=[ 3818]
   bw (  KiB/s): min=614400, max=1093632, per=100.00%, avg=889105.49, stdev=204457.74, samples=37
   iops        : min=  300, max=  534, avg=434.08, stdev=99.89, samples=37
  lat (usec)   : 750=1.75%, 1000=15.58%
  lat (msec)   : 2=82.63%, 4=0.05%
  cpu          : usr=6.88%, sys=47.06%, ctx=9040, majf=0, minf=22
  IO depths    : 1=100.0%, 2=0.0%, 4=0.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwt: total=0,8295,0, short=0,0,0, dropped=0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=1

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
  WRITE: bw=829MiB/s (870MB/s), 829MiB/s-829MiB/s (870MB/s-870MB/s), io=16.2GiB (17.4GB), run=20001-20001msec

Disk stats (read/write):
  nvme0n1: ios=0/16381, merge=0/9, ticks=0/23476, in_queue=23460, util=73.80%
```

This starts to look very different when switching off direct write.

```
fio --name=seq_write --filename=testfile --size=10G --bs=2m --rw=write --time_based --runtime=20 --direct=0 --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=1 --output=seq-write.out
```

```
seq_write: (g=0): rw=write, bs=(R) 2048KiB-2048KiB, (W) 2048KiB-2048KiB, (T) 2048KiB-2048KiB, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=1
fio-3.1
Starting 1 process

seq_write: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=1461: Tue Mar  9 17:25:12 2021
  write: IOPS=130, BW=260MiB/s (273MB/s)(5206MiB/20003msec)
    slat (msec): min=6, max=108, avg= 7.19, stdev= 2.06
    clat (usec): min=14, max=346, avg=20.14, stdev= 7.23
     lat (msec): min=6, max=108, avg= 7.22, stdev= 2.06
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[   16],  5.00th=[   19], 10.00th=[   19], 20.00th=[   20],
     | 30.00th=[   20], 40.00th=[   20], 50.00th=[   21], 60.00th=[   21],
     | 70.00th=[   21], 80.00th=[   21], 90.00th=[   21], 95.00th=[   22],
     | 99.00th=[   24], 99.50th=[   37], 99.90th=[   65], 99.95th=[  122],
     | 99.99th=[  347]
   bw (  KiB/s): min=176128, max=294912, per=100.00%, avg=280496.89, stdev=21426.33, samples=38
   iops        : min=   86, max=  144, avg=136.95, stdev=10.47, samples=38
  lat (usec)   : 20=50.33%, 50=49.29%, 100=0.31%, 250=0.04%, 500=0.04%
  cpu          : usr=1.90%, sys=96.59%, ctx=810, majf=0, minf=20
  IO depths    : 1=100.0%, 2=0.0%, 4=0.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwt: total=0,2603,0, short=0,0,0, dropped=0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=1

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
  WRITE: bw=260MiB/s (273MB/s), 260MiB/s-260MiB/s (273MB/s-273MB/s), io=5206MiB (5459MB), run=20003-20003msec

Disk stats (read/write):
  nvme0n1: ios=0/4558, merge=0/6, ticks=0/286996, in_queue=286996, util=15.04%
```

the performance drops to around 260 MB/s. This drop appears to be CPU bound. I am wondering if there is something I could do on the kernel side to improve the write performance. I've asked a similar question on the NVIDIA forum on [performance degradation between TX1 and TX2](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvme-ssd-write-performance-degradation-between-tx1-and-tx2/111009).

Answer (score 0):

(Thanks for including the relevant `fio` output in your question and formatting it - it really helps!)

[Linux AIO (as used by fio's `libaio` ioengine) can become blocking when you don't use direct I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46377629/2732969) (see point 1) but since your `iodepth` is only 1 you might be better off using a synchronous I/O engine (e.g. `pvsync2`) as you're paying for asynchronous machinery you're choosing not to use (could you elaborate on why?). The stats you are posting appear to be sending a warning (could you post your thoughts on the **different types** of latencies present in your jobs above)?

Additionally when your second `fio` "ends" in your second run you have no way of knowing how much of the I/O is still only rolling around in the Linux kernel cache so it's not clear what you're trying to compare. In both jobs you're going through a filesystem, so that may complicate what you're measuring. The casual answerer can't tell how much RAM your machine has and we don't know at which point the kernel HAS to start flushing I/O in order to make space for more buffered I/O...

TLDR; As a random passerby I'd need to see more to have a complete picture so I can't say anything concrete. However, what you've posted makes your benchmark methodology look suspicious - maybe you're benchmarking something different to what you expect?